# Dateformat with category axis amcharts4

Tags: typescript, amcharts

The dateformat property is not working in amcharts4.

I understand that the dateformat is inherited from the parent element, I've tried setting the dateformat at a chart level, axis level, and series level.

```
 chart.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
```

Please see codepen below:

https://codepen.io/alex-wells/pen/vQmWBz

Comment: Is that codepen is your code?

Comment: @Aroon I've updated the codepen example I think I might've made an error when creating the question.

Comment: The dates are coming from json or manually by you? If it is json you should change the dateformat from json file end

Comment: I could format the date before I send it to amcharts, but my intention was to pass the data and use the dateformatter class to configure the format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from @martynasma on github

> You are using CategoryAxis. This axis treats all of the categories as
>   text, hence no formatting applied.
>
> If you need proper date axis, you need to use DateAxis, as well as use
>   dateX for series' dataFields:
>
> ```
> var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
> ```
>
> ....
>
> ```
> series1.dataFields.dateX = "category";
> series1.dataFields.valueY = "value1";
> ```
>
> Now, setting format for the DateAxis is not as straightforward as
>   setting dateFormat. This axis type have multiple levels of
>   granularity, so you need to set for your target one. In your case it's
>   a day.
>
> ```
> dateAxis.dateFormats.setKey("day", "dd/MM/yyyy");
> dateAxis.periodChangeDateFormats.setKey("day", "dd/MM/yyyy");
> ```
>
> More info:
>
> https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/dateaxis/#dateFormats_property
>   https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/dateaxis/#periodChangeDateFormats_property
>
> And here's your pen updated as per above:
>
> https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/pQPQdN?editors=0010